# Which one is true, are or is?

Tags: grammatical-number

So when we say
-My sister and brothers
We use are because of "brothers"
But if i say
-My sisters and brother
What is the correct word to use? Are or is?

Comment: Grammatically it should be *are*, even though it sounds awkward, and many people might get it wrong for that reason. If it were me I would say "*my brother and sisters* are coming"

Comment: Yes I agree on the first statement which is "My brother and sisters are". But the one I was asking about was the second statement which is "My brothers and sister"

Comment: @WS2 is "my sisters and brother are..." doesn't sound awkward to me in the least. Also not awkward: "my sister and brother are..." and "Jack and Jill are...."

Comment: You cannot use *true* this way in English!!!

Answer (score 0):

Even if you only have one brother and one sister, "are" is still correct:

> My brother and sister are coming.

A native English speaker would never say "My brother and sister is coming."